# Where do the /idp/ endpoints come from?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

I am trying to setup an authentication mechanism based on the new OIOSAML3.0. Using your https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp works fine for me.

However, having moved the various startup calls over into my own code I get a HTTP 404 on the redirects to *'/idp/saml/3.0/?...'*

The same thing happends when I take your example, but change over to my own organisation metadata.

I thought these endpoints would be setup by the call to **AddSaml2()** and **UseSaml2()** in Startup.cs but that does not seem to be the case.

Can you lend any insight into where and how these endspoints are added to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IdP endpoint is read from the NemLog-in metadata. I the sample the NemLog-in metadata is in the `TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp-metadata.xml` file.

The NemLog-in metadata is read in [Startup.cs line 39](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Startup.cs#L39). And the endpoints is read in line [43](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Startup.cs#L43) and [44](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Startup.cs#L44).